# Problem with float and pictures in LaTex

Tags: layout, latex, figure

The picture is at the position of the header:
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/%20latex1.png

Code:

```
\begin{figure}
   \subfloat[A gull]{\label{fig:gull}\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{p1.png}}
   \subfloat[A tiger]{\label{fig:tiger}\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{p2.png}}
   \caption{Pictures of animals}      
   \label{fig:animals}      
\end{figure}
```

Code before \begin{document}:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   

\usepackage{amsmath}            
\usepackage{amsfonts}           
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{verbatim}           % by \begin{comment}---\end{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}                
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}   

\floatname{program}{Program}
\cfoot{\ }  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\title{Applying a}
```

What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figures *float*.

That is, TeX moves them around to accommodate its typesetting needs. You have the option of specifying what types of places you want TeX to *try* to put them using:

```
\begin{figure}[htpb]
   ...
\end{figure}
```

where the options mean:

```
h -- here
t -- top
b -- bottom
p -- page (on a page-o-floats)
H -- Absolutely right here (but requires the `float` package)
```

Using `!` in the options will tell TeX to try *hard* to put it near the things it is adjacent to in the source file. The default positioning is `tbp`, so "here" is not even an option unless you ask for it. Also note that the ordering of the options is irrelevant, so `[p!bh]` will give the same result as `[!hbp]`.

So try **`\begin{figure}[h!]`** (or **`\begin{figure}[H]`** if you have already done `\usepackage{float}`)

The same options are available for tables and any other floats you define.

Comment: It is strange, when that works in pdflatex, but not in rubber.