# No indent for paragraphs after figures?

Tags: latex, indentation, paragraph

The default style for my document is that paragraphs are indented. That's fine. But I need no indentation for paragraphs that follow a figure or other objects.

Using `\noindent` manually does not work well, because you don't know which paragraph will follow the figure in the final output (LaTeX places figures automatically).

So I need paragraphs that follow figures *in the output* to not be indented (in the tex source you can't see which ones that would be). How can that be achieved?

Comment: What happens when a figure falls in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: There still shouldn't be any indentation in that case. But I don't think LaTeX ever does that, it rather puts the figure on a separate page.

Comment: If TeX isn't turing complete, this is not a programming question.

Comment: TeX _is_ Turing complete. And is used in some inline documentation specifications. And (less relevant, I'll admit) writing large documents _feels_ like programming. Cheers.

Comment: How about not indenting *any* paragraphs?  Ie, change the style to use a bit of vertical whitespace and no indentation for new paragraphs.  (I'm also curious why you care about indentation after figures.)

Comment: You can use `[H]` as its placement specifier for figures to place the figure exactly where it is in the LaTeX code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like checking which paragraphs come after figures and putting `\noindent` in front of everyone manually is the only way to do this.

Answer (score 10):

I usally just put "\\" just after the figure.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a very strange request (as well as difficult to satisfy). The `figure` environment is for objects which are related to, but not part of the text stream.

Here are some suggestions for alternative approaches you might consider:

- If you insist, you can exert some modest control of the figure placement. See [Problem with float and pictures in LaTex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518284/problem-with-float-and-pictures-in-latex).
- You could increase the amount of white-space separating figures and the body of text. Lookup `\textfloatsep`, `\intextsep`, `\abovecaptionskip`, and `\belowcaptionskip`.
- You could try some of the tools in the [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/) or [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/) packages.

Answer (score 2):

My publisher requires the same thing (so the suggestions as not-indenting no paragraph or not doing such a strange thing is out of question). \

I did not find any automatic solution. Instead, I placed as many figures as possible to top or bottom of the page and then manually inserted \noindent after all figures that are placed inline Unfortunately, since the 'h' flag is only a recommendation one has to compile, check output, place indent, compile, check output not place indent, took me about 1 hour for a book of 300 pages.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I got deep into latex, so I hope it's ok if I just offer a rough idea - and I'm not at all sure it will work:

IIRC, latex allows you to define your own [counters](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm). You could change the figure formatting environment to increment a custom counter, then make the paragraph code set a conditional indent (only if counter equals 1), and subsequently make it reset the counter.

(can't find my latex book either, my wife took it!)

Edit: more thoughts on this - have a look at the topnumber/bottomnumber counters, which are used by Latex to count how many floats it has placed on a page. You will want to use a very similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` before `\begin{document}`. 
I use the following:

```tex
\setlength{\parident}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1cm}
\begin{document}
  .............
```

Note that `\parskip` sets the spacing between paragraphs to 1cm.