# Inserting images in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a question on inserting images into a LaTeX document. I try to insert images using the keyboard short cut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and I'm able to insert images. But the compiled pdf document shows all the images at the end, whereas I want to interleave images with text. Something like the following:

```
Text1
Image1
Text2
Image2
Text3
Image3
```

I try to insert images at right positions i.e. in between text, but on compilation, they all appear at the end. I have tried different options provided on the image insertion UI but same result.

Any idea where I'm going wrong.

Related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518284/problem-with-float-and-pictures-in-latex/518418#518418).

Comment: What keyboard shortcut is that?

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts? "image insertion UI"? This isn't any LaTeX I'm familiar with. What app are you using?

Comment: That "related" question should give you exactly the answer you need.

Comment: The editor is by TeXnicCenter (free editor for developing LaTeX documents in windows) and doing a Ctrl-Alt-G in there shows up a GUI with a title 'Insert Figure'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try downsizing the images. Maybe they are too large and so they are moved to the end of the document..

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

You'll have to use [graphicx package](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

and then you just use \includegraphics

```
\includegraphics{myfig.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=60mm]{myfig.png}
\includegraphics[height=60mm]{myfig.jpg}
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{myfig.pdf}
\includegraphics[angle=45,width=52mm]{myfig.jpg}
```

Comment: You definitely want to use some variation of the \begin{figure} environment! I don't think the author has any problem with inserting the figures themselves.

Answer (score 4):

What code did you use for the \figure environment? In most cases the "h" option should at least help a little bit there.

Answer (score 3):

This is a FAQ: "[Moving tables and figures in LaTeX](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=floats)". Note especially the third dot point, which relaxes some of the restrictions LaTeX uses to position floats.

That's the best answer I can give without seeing an example of how large your floats are and how you're inserting them into the document. Provided that they're reasonably-sized, you should have no problem with

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics{myfig}
  \caption{...}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

And note that if the float is too large to fit then it *will* move to a subsequent page -- this is the whole idea behind getting LaTeX to help you with the formatting. You certainly don't want to end a page prematurely just because there's a figure coming up next that otherwise doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you in general...I just hate the LaTeX way of making everything too advanced (flexible) at all times.
Beside, the source looks really awful.
It will not solve you initial problem, but since it will be easier to change size of each image you can at least try...

```
% Easy image insert
%   use as \img{imagename}{caption}{label}
%   will insert image with with 70% of textwidth
%   change below for other width
\newcommand{\img}[3]{
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{#1}
        \caption{#2}
        \label{fig:#3}
    \end{figure}
}
```

\img{myimage}{has this caption}{and_this_label}

the label is automatically prefixed with fig:.
Good luck!
/C

Answer (score 1):

Using [!t] and [!h] in the figure environment, rather than [t], [h] etc seems to help, though I've yet to find a surefire way to get large images in sensible places. Sometimes it works half way through a document, othertimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just changing the width or height using an option to the includegraphics statement (square brackets before the filename a.k.a `\includegraphics[width=foo]{}`) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure}[H!]
  \includegraphics{myfig}
  \caption{...}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

Use `H!` to denote that you want your picture right there.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 text
\begin{figure}[tbh]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4 \textheight]{ & directory path of jpg. width defines the width of the page and one one can put in its place height which is text page height }

\caption{name of the jpg} 
\end{figure}
% it worked for me.

\end{document}
```