# Figures in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How do you have a figure imported so that it appears on the bottom of a page with a caption? When I import it and put a caption on it normally, it always appears at the top of a page.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518284/problem-with-float-and-pictures-in-latex

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{figure}[b]
 your figure
\end{figure}
```

See this link, for more syntax:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures

Answer (score 1):

Just an example:

**Caption below**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{thatcat.jpg}
  \caption{That cat!} % caption line
\end{figure}
```

[image: caption below]

**Caption above**

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{That cat!} % caption line
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{thatcat.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

[image: caption above]

Comment: if i'd like to have tet between two figures how can i do it ?

Comment: @FadyKamal what does "tet" mean?

Comment: @FadyKamal I think you'll need to use a package to include multiple figures, like `subfig` or `subfigure`. Then, you'll just need to put your caption between the two `subfigures`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to freyrs:

If if you put `\caption` above the `\includegraphics` the caption will be above the figure, if you put `\caption` below the `\includegraphics` the caption will appear below the figure.